# how to pass query parameter to .Net Maui ViewModel

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, mvvm, maui

In my receiving Viewmodel I want to reference the [QueryParameter] in my async method GetMovies() and run it to populate the page with Movies. I have placed the breakpoint at the GetMovies method in the MovieListGenrePageViewModel. When it is called, selectedGenre is null but it is been return in {Binding} . What am I missing?

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;
using TimesNewsApp.Models;
using TimesNewsApp.Services;

namespace TimesNewsApp.ViewModels
{
    [QueryProperty(nameof(SelectedGenre), nameof(SelectedGenre))]
    public partial class MovieListGenrePageViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Result> Movie { get;} = new();


        private Genre selectedGenre;

        public Genre SelectedGenre
        {
            get => selectedGenre;
            set
            {
                SetProperty(ref selectedGenre, value);
            }
        }

        NewsApiManager apiService;

        public Command GetMovieComand { get; }

        public MovieListGenrePageViewModel(NewsApiManager apiService)
        {
            this.apiService = apiService;

            Task.Run(async () => await GetMovies(SelectedGenre));
            
        }


        async Task GetMovies(Genre SelectedGenre)
        {
            if (IsBusy)
                return;
            try
            {
                IsBusy = true;
                if (SelectedGenre == null)
                    return;
                
                Movie movies = await apiService.GetMovieByGenre(27);
                if (Movie.Count != 0)
                    return;
                foreach (var item in movies.results)
                    Movie.Add(item);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine($"Unable to get movie: {ex.Message}");
                await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Error!", ex.Message, "OK");
            }
            finally
            {
                IsBusy = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the constructor executes before properties are set

Comment: Thanks @Jason how can I fix this?

Comment: pass the parameter on the constructor, or wail until the property is set to call `GetMovies`

Comment: I try passing the parameter like this, but SelectedGenre returns null ```public MovieListGenrePageViewModel(NewsApiManager apiService)
        {
            this.apiService = apiService;
            this.SelectedGenre = SelectedGenre;
            Task.Run(async () => await GetMovies(SelectedGenre));
            
        }```

Comment: that is not passing the parameter in the constructor

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247157/discussion-between-toby-nwude-and-jason).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can  check the following parts first:

1.check parameter `SelectedGenre` is correct:

```cs
[QueryProperty(nameof(SelectedGenre), nameof(SelectedGenre))]
```

2.debug to see if code `SetProperty(ref selectedGenre, value);` can been executed:

```cs
public Genre SelectedGenre
{
    get => selectedGenre;
    set
    {
        SetProperty(ref selectedGenre, value);
    }
}
```

3.try to add function `GetMovies` as follows:

```cs
private Genre selectedGenre;

public Genre SelectedGenre
{
    get => selectedGenre;
    set
    {
        SetProperty(ref selectedGenre, value);
        //add function GetMovies here

        Task.Run(async () => await GetMovies(value));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use MVVM toolkit to do the same.

```
[ObservableProperty]
private string? name;

partial void OnNameChanging(string? value)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Name is about to change to {value}");
}

partial void OnNameChanged(string? value)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Name has changed to {value}");
}
```

[Docs Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/mvvm/generators/observableproperty#notifying-dependent-commands)