# .Net MAUI query parameter not passing thru

Tags: c#, .net-maui, maui-community-toolkit

I am trying to pass a query parameter from one `ViewModel` to another. I have a separate .Net MAUI solution where the query parameter is working, but for some reason the exact same setup won't work in my primary solution.

The navigation itself works and the `listId` has a value from `MainViewModel` navigation. I have the .NET MAUI Community Toolkit package installed. Have I missed a setup step?

**MainViewModel.cs**

```
[RelayCommand]
async Task GoToList(int listId)
{
     await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"{nameof(ListPage)}?ListId={listId}");
}
```

**ListViewModel.cs**

```
[QueryProperty("ListId", "ListId")]
public partial class ListViewModel : ObservableObject
{
   [ObservableProperty]
    int listId;
}
```

**AppShell.cs**

```
public AppShell()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(ListPage), typeof(ListPage));
}
```

**MauiProgram.cs**

```
public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
{
    var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();

    builder.Services.AddTransient<MainPage>();
    builder.Services.AddTransient<MainViewModel>();

    builder.Services.AddTransient<ListPage>();
    builder.Services.AddTransient<ListViewModel>();

    return builder.Build();
}
```

Comment: Solved it by implementing the solution from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73301982/6804444).

Answer (score 3):

Solved it by implementing the solution from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73301982/6804444).

```
private int listId;
public int ListId
{
       get => listId;
       set
         {
             SetProperty(ref listId, value);

             //Use ListId here
         }
}
```

Comment: FWIW: Were you previously trying to use `listId` in the constructor? Note that since you didn't show, in question, *where* you used listId, there is no way anyone else could have spotted the problem. Remember to always show all related code (in this case, where it is used).

Comment: Yes, I will. Didn't hide where I was using it by intention. Just missed it. But I'll definitely share all related code to the question.

Comment: Yes I know. But the ui is blocking me from doing that for 48 hours. 8 hours left.

Comment: 21 minutes left