# Unable to pass a value to another page

Tags: c#, xaml, .net-6.0, maui

I have the following app which has a CollectionView populated from an SQLite database, but I am having difficulty passing the selected value from the CollectionView to another page when clicked on.

Records.cs

```
using SQLite;

namespace b_records.Models
{
    [Table("records)")]
    public class Record
    {
        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(250)]
        public string Amount { get; set; }
    }
}
```

AppShell.xaml.cs

```
namespace b_records;

public partial class AppShell : Shell
{
    public AppShell()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Routing.RegisterRoute("DetailPage", typeof(DetailPage));
    }
}
```

MainPage.xaml

```
<CollectionView x:Name="recordList" Grid.Row="5" SelectionChanged="OnCollectionViewSelectionChanged" SelectionMode="Single">
    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>

                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <Label Text="{Binding Id}" />
                <Label Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Amount}" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
private async void OnCollectionViewSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    int id = (e.CurrentSelection.FirstOrDefault() as Record).Id;
    await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"DetailPage?id={id}");
}
```

DetailPage.xaml.cs

```
namespace b_records;

[QueryProperty(nameof(id), "id")]
public partial class DetailPage : ContentPage
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public DetailPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        lblText.Text = id.ToString();
    }
}
```

Trying to follow the details from Microsoft's documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/navigation?view=net-maui-6.0#pass-data

But each time I click on the CollectionView, I am taken to DetailPage, and the value in the lblText.text is 0 instead of the id value on the row in the CollectionView populated from the SQLite database.

Any idea why?

Comment: where is the code where you actually navigate to `DetailPage`?

Comment: Sorry, I have now added the MainPage.xaml.cs code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to pass query parameter to .Net Maui ViewModel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73293779/how-to-pass-query-parameter-to-net-maui-viewmodel)

Comment: Have you put breakpoint on `await Shell.Current.GoToAsync..`, to verify that `id` is not `0`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constructor is **the first thing called** when any object is created. (With possible exception of initialization values directly on data members.) NO property values have been set at that time. Thus, `id` has not been set.

One solution is to move any code that needs any query value, into override of OnAppearing:

```cs
protected override void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();

    lblText.Text = id.ToString();
}
```

---

Alternative solution is to move that line into property setter:

```cs
public int id {
  get => _id;
  set
  {
    SetProperty(ref _id, value);
    lblText.Text = value.ToString();
  }
}
private int _id;
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the constructor of page `DetailPage` is called before getting the passed value `id`.

```
public DetailPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    lblText.Text = id.ToString();
}
```

So, you can try the following code:

```
[QueryProperty(nameof(id), "id")] 
public partial class DetailPage : ContentPage
{
    //public string id { get; set; }
    public int id
    {
        set
        {
            LoadDetail(value);
        }
    }
    public DetailPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //lblText.Text = id.ToString();
    }

    void LoadDetail(int id)
    {
        try
        {
            lblText.Text = id.ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Failed.");
        }
    }
}
```